# use OpenOffice Calc to open Excel files and convert to CSV or Tab-delimited

Tags: excel, automation, openoffice-calc

Is there any type of automation available where I can use OpenOffice Calc to open Excel files and convert them to CSV or tab-delimited files?

I'm currently using PHPExcel to open the files and iterate through them and import each row into a database but have begun to run into memory issues with large files and need another alternative.

These are xls and xlsx files so it has to work for all of them.

If there is, how would I go about programming this in PHP?
If you have other alternatives, please feel free to suggest them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenOffice can be run in server mode and used to convert files between a number of supported formats.

I have used this mainly with Java thru the JODConverter library available at http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter

A quick websearch brought up http://sourceforge.net/projects/phopo-org/ which claims to be a PHP implementation

Comment: [quote]http://sourceforge.net/projects/phopo-org/ [/quote]        _This project has no files._

Comment: _JODConverter_ Doesn't look like it does xlsx files. How would I use this from PHP, anyway?

Comment: It can be used as a command line tool invoked from a PHP script - http://www.artofsolving.com/node/13. Since version 2.2.2 it does support the new Office formats looks like the documentation on the website hasn't been updated.